# Add an image in a template which is an image too

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to add an image to a template which is another image too; Im using PHP codeigniter ; I tried image_lib, the documenattion of which is "https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html", but it seems it does not provide this option. 
could you please let me know if there is any way to put an image in (middle or anyware of) another image?

If my question is not clear, please let me know and I will provide more clarification!

Many thanks,

Comment: Have you considered doing things such as creating a table with a background image, then overlaying your image in a cell? You could potentially position it however you like, and even vary it quite easily. Not sure what the "correct" method is, but overlaying images isn't a common thing in web design... If something isn't visible, why bother making the user download it?

Comment: Thanks XtrmJosh for your response! Thats one of the possibilities, but after creating the table, how can I create an image of my created table? I need to output an image, in which a picture is placed in a template which is already an image too.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't quite get that part of the question, I'm not well educated enough in PHP to create a snapshot like that, but I'm sure there are methods to do so. I did a very small amount of work on it some time ago, and I used this resource to help me through the process: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/image_creation_with_php_formats.html

Good luck, and sorry I cannot help further

Comment: Why don't you use the watermark function of the `image_lib` class in codeigniter?

Comment: @XtrmJosh: using tables for layouts is so 1990s...

Comment: @ WebNovice: if I understood correctly with watermark function we can add messages which are generated using text! Not images! Maybe I'm mistaken! Could you please let me know if I can add an image to another image with this function? Thanks

Comment: How about converting my template image to PDF and putting my image in that template by FPDF and then converting PDF to image? can I convert the output PDF to image using imagemagic? if so, how can I do that (the last step)? Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596879/php-adding-images-to-another-image-exact-positioning?

Comment: Thanks; I wish there way a way to accept your comment as a solution man...

Answer (score 2):

Probably you won't use CodeIgniter for that. http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php